# Reload View from Modal View Controller with CoreData in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, modalviewcontroller

I was following a YouTube tutorial on how to create a to-do list with CoreData and my app can build and run however instead of using another view controller to create a task, I created a modal view controller to be displayed over the regular view controller. The problem is it saves it to the CoreData but only displays when the app is reset, this is all the code used for the regular view controller where the tasks should appear:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewTest: UITableView!

var tasks : [Task] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableViewTest.dataSource = self
    tableViewTest.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getData()

    tableViewTest.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableViewTest: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tasks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableViewTest: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = task.name!
    return cell
}

func getData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print("Fetch Error")
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

and this is the code for the modal view controller where the user enter is information to be saved to CoreData:

```
class popVCAdd: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var popViewAc: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    popViewAc.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    popViewAc.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    let keyboardDone = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.disappearKey))
    toolbar.setItems([keyboardDone], animated: false)
}

@IBAction func doneBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    let task = Task(context: context) 

    task.name = textField.text!

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

}

@IBAction func dismissPop(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
}

    func disappearKey() {
     view.endEditing(true)

    }
```

}

Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Comment: This is because you have to Store it into Persistence Storage and get it again. After that you have to reload table data.  I could help if you share your Code where you are stroing it into Core data.

Comment: It is very simple that when you are stroing you new data into Core Data, You need to write logic to which you have written in ViewWillApper : getData()
tableViewTest.reloadData()

Comment: Thanks! I did save it to persistent storage with the add button and said saveContext within the UIButton. Is that what you meant by save it to persistent storage? Also what is strong? Thanks again!

Comment: I 100% got your issue. But the thing is without seeing your code i am not able to help you.

Comment: Is it like :  (ControllerA which is showing list of task) and  (ControllerB which is Adding your task into CoreData). So what code i want to see is the One Which is Adding Task into Core Data and after saving it intoCore dat hwat you are doing?

Comment: Yeah it is sort of like you said, I added all the code to the project and the second one is the modal view controller A.K.A ControllerB where the info will get saved and the first one is showing the list of tasks. Sorry if the code is messy, very new to Xcode. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please add a breakpoint on override func viewWillAppear check whether it is calling or not after dismiss  your modalcontroller.

Comment: I added a break point only to the override func view WillAppear and when running it on my iPhone just gave a white screen, I am not sure what you mean by whether it is calling when I dismiss the modalcontroller. Just added a break point and ran.

Comment: Please share your action Method Code of ViewController from where you are Presenting your  Modal controller for adding new task. That code is missing above. Or have you addded segue using storyboard? I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by Method Code (only started using Xcode about 2 weeks ago), for the modal view controller I used a segue in the main.storyboard called "Present Modally".

Comment: Yes i want to know the same which you just share that used a segue in the main.storyboard called "Present Modally". It not seems to be any issue  in your code. But let me check deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change you `ModalPresantaion` Style to **`Full Screen`**

See Below Screen Shot:

**`Select Segue First:`**

[image]

**`Change Its Presantation Style to Full Screen:`**

[image]

I am Suggesting you above changes because:

`viewWillAppear` of your `ViewController` is not calling after `Dismissing` from your `popVCAdd` Controller.